# Failing to create JuJu controller on openstack/microstack bare metal

Tags: openstack, juju

I am following these steps https://microstack.run/docs/using-juju and I cannot seem to create a controller. i get error message `20:23:24 ERROR juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:884 failed to bootstrap model: cannot start bootstrap instance: no metadata for "bionic" images in microstack with arch amd64`

I installed openstack single node installation followed all instructions in the guides.

I have tried logging into horizon as admin and add metadata `series` and `arch` to the image uploaded via cli but it does not work.

full log

```
# juju bootstrap --bootstrap-series=$OS_SERIES   --metadata-source=~/simplestreams   --model-default network=test   --model-default external-network=external   --model-default use-floating-ip=true   microstack microstack --debug
20:23:22 INFO  juju.cmd supercommand.go:56 running juju [2.9.31 0f2ce8e528a67fa3f735dff39a1a68c44540bb97 gc go1.18.2]
20:23:22 DEBUG juju.cmd supercommand.go:57   args: []string{"/snap/juju/19414/bin/juju", "bootstrap", "--bootstrap-series=bionic", "--metadata-source=~/simplestreams", "--model-default", "network=test", "--model-default", "external-network=external", "--model-default", "use-floating-ip=true", "microstack", "microstack", "--debug"}
20:23:22 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:1307 authenticating with region "" and credential "admin" ()
20:23:22 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:1455 provider attrs: map[external-network:external network:test policy-target-group: use-default-secgroup:false use-floating-ip:true use-openstack-gbp:false]
20:23:23 INFO  cmd authkeys.go:114 Adding contents of "/root/.local/share/juju/ssh/juju_id_rsa.pub" to authorized-keys
20:23:23 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:1530 preparing controller with config: map[agent-metadata-url: agent-stream:released apt-ftp-proxy: apt-http-proxy: apt-https-proxy: apt-mirror: apt-no-proxy: authorized-keys:ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDnkIQi6rQURr822ggum4NZtdY68kCJRgS0l9YrjGvnYhWLwuj0h2/nA81MVSDOLqy4aRmQCqIlGAcWVj+0cagwz0iIvkZK6U9CIpCmNjsd6bvV+nVvDaAnFK5/AwkYixflOV867q2ybCuLkUNVIYgUzHY/FMhvFMcgl9Ldxs+2KDKaRam78x2xsp/zPs05bKpPVJoCAkABcSFBBvfMsNlqu07He7Y4tsZJaFvti/mV+rO1N41UMerWbPcH1VkqvVVGqZNTPR3fSVZsVmWFs1L0w5P4+AaKrvHW74WFg/wLDmUEwj5rybDK5H1aEoJPggtP6+QhSpPFAYIPRTdASeJx juju-client-key
 automatically-retry-hooks:true backup-dir: charmhub-url:https://api.charmhub.io cloudinit-userdata: container-image-metadata-url: container-image-stream:released container-inherit-properties: container-networking-method: default-series:focal default-space: development:false disable-network-management:false disable-telemetry:false egress-subnets: enable-os-refresh-update:true enable-os-upgrade:true external-network:external fan-config: firewall-mode:instance ftp-proxy: http-proxy: https-proxy: ignore-machine-addresses:false image-metadata-url: image-stream:released juju-ftp-proxy: juju-http-proxy: juju-https-proxy: juju-no-proxy:127.0.0.1,localhost,::1 logforward-enabled:false logging-config: logging-output: lxd-snap-channel:latest/stable max-action-results-age:336h max-action-results-size:5G max-status-history-age:336h max-status-history-size:5G name:controller net-bond-reconfigure-delay:17 network:test no-proxy:127.0.0.1,localhost,::1 num-container-provision-workers:4 num-provision-workers:16 policy-target-group: provisioner-harvest-mode:destroyed proxy-ssh:false resource-tags: snap-http-proxy: snap-https-proxy: snap-store-assertions: snap-store-proxy: snap-store-proxy-url: ssl-hostname-verification:true test-mode:false transmit-vendor-metrics:true type:openstack update-status-hook-interval:5m use-default-secgroup:false use-floating-ip:true use-openstack-gbp:false uuid:414283ed-20ff-4226-8bf5-762dc6414ca4]
20:23:23 INFO  juju.provider.openstack provider.go:169 opening model "controller"
20:23:23 WARN  juju.provider.openstack config.go:181 Config attribute "use-floating-ip" is deprecated.
You can instead use the constraint "allocate-public-ip".
20:23:23 DEBUG juju.provider.openstack provider.go:979 authURL: https://10.255.52.101:5000/v3
20:23:23 DEBUG juju.provider.openstack provider.go:979 authURL: https://10.255.52.101:5000/v3
20:23:23 DEBUG goose logger.go:44 DEBUG: auth details: &{Token:gAAAAABis3o7i7xAk0aKxVqGM032h27eTaab39ody8-PDV4hNAgylnlhvdmFV1AaK6Sn5IkYj43T5jCB97JvdvDYSjG5Yk1koYz3NO7PDmASw24jnuXidKC8-yJC8pp9emNaA0GEprkUhP7TOKs7K5VIzwrUO6BOqBNDvpWmXrFP2aZUMvmwCds TenantId:75a496aa41f944a4bd867557bcc7489d TenantName:admin UserId:47980441e7bb47a69473b734091e19d5 Domain: RegionServiceURLs:map[microstack:map[compute:https://10.255.52.101:8774/v2.1 identity:https://10.255.52.101:5000/v3/ image:https://10.255.52.101:9292 network:https://10.255.52.101:9696 placement:https://10.255.52.101:8778 volumev2:https://10.255.52.101:8776/v2/75a496aa41f944a4bd867557bcc7489d volumev3:https://10.255.52.101:8776/v3/75a496aa41f944a4bd867557bcc7489d]]}
20:23:23 INFO  cmd bootstrap.go:855 Creating Juju controller "microstack" on microstack/microstack
20:23:23 DEBUG goose logger.go:44 TRACE: api version will be inserted between "https://10.255.52.101:8774/" and "/"
20:23:23 DEBUG goose logger.go:44 DEBUG: discovered API versions: [{Version:{Major:2 Minor:0} Links:[{Href:http://127.0.0.1:8764/v2/ Rel:self}] Status:SUPPORTED} {Version:{Major:2 Minor:1} Links:[{Href:http://127.0.0.1:8764/v2.1/ Rel:self}] Status:CURRENT}]
20:23:23 DEBUG goose logger.go:44 TRACE: MakeServiceURL: https://10.255.52.101:8774/v2.1/flavors/detail
20:23:24 INFO  juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:921 combined bootstrap constraints: 
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:320 model "controller" supports application/machine networks: true
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:322 network management by juju enabled: true
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:1065 no agent directory found, using default agent metadata source: https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:1090 setting default image metadata source: /root/simplestreams/images
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:423 searching for signed metadata in datasource "bootstrap metadata"
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:458 looking for data index using path streams/v1/index2.sjson
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:470 looking for data index using URL file:///root/simplestreams/images/streams/v1/index2.sjson
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:473 streams/v1/index2.sjson not accessed, actual error: [{/build/snapcraft-juju-25888574271dd1b08771e6ebeeab8ad6/parts/juju/src/environs/simplestreams/datasource.go:192: "file:///root/simplestreams/images/streams/v1/index2.sjson" not found}]
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:474 streams/v1/index2.sjson not accessed, trying legacy index path: streams/v1/index.sjson
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:489 cannot load index "file:///root/simplestreams/images/streams/v1/index.sjson": "file:///root/simplestreams/images/streams/v1/index.sjson" not found
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:427 falling back to search for unsigned metadata in datasource "bootstrap metadata"
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:458 looking for data index using path streams/v1/index2.json
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:470 looking for data index using URL file:///root/simplestreams/images/streams/v1/index2.json
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:473 streams/v1/index2.json not accessed, actual error: [{/build/snapcraft-juju-25888574271dd1b08771e6ebeeab8ad6/parts/juju/src/environs/simplestreams/datasource.go:192: "file:///root/simplestreams/images/streams/v1/index2.json" not found}]
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:474 streams/v1/index2.json not accessed, trying legacy index path: streams/v1/index.json
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:493 read metadata index at "file:///root/simplestreams/images/streams/v1/index.json"
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:1025 finding products at path "streams/v1/com.ubuntu.cloud-released-imagemetadata.json"
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs imagemetadata.go:45 new user image datasource registered: bootstrap metadata
20:23:24 INFO  juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:1127 custom image metadata added to search path
20:23:24 INFO  cmd bootstrap.go:397 Loading image metadata
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs imagemetadata.go:119 obtained image datasource "bootstrap metadata"
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs imagemetadata.go:119 obtained image datasource "default ubuntu cloud images"
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:959 constraints for image metadata lookup &{{{microstack https://10.255.52.101:5000/v3} [disco xenial win2012hvr2 centos8 opensuseleap win2012hv win2016nano eoan yakkety quantal trusty saucy raring genericlinux win2008r2 bionic vivid utopic win7 win8 win81 kubernetes focal zesty centos7 win2016hv wily win10 win2012r2 precise impish cosmic artful win2012 centos9 win2016 win2019 jammy hirsute groovy] [amd64 i386 armhf arm64 ppc64el s390x] released}}
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:423 searching for signed metadata in datasource "bootstrap metadata"
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:458 looking for data index using path streams/v1/index2.sjson
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:470 looking for data index using URL file:///root/simplestreams/images/streams/v1/index2.sjson
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:473 streams/v1/index2.sjson not accessed, actual error: [{/build/snapcraft-juju-25888574271dd1b08771e6ebeeab8ad6/parts/juju/src/environs/simplestreams/datasource.go:192: "file:///root/simplestreams/images/streams/v1/index2.sjson" not found}]
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:474 streams/v1/index2.sjson not accessed, trying legacy index path: streams/v1/index.sjson
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:489 cannot load index "file:///root/simplestreams/images/streams/v1/index.sjson": "file:///root/simplestreams/images/streams/v1/index.sjson" not found
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:427 falling back to search for unsigned metadata in datasource "bootstrap metadata"
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:458 looking for data index using path streams/v1/index2.json
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:470 looking for data index using URL file:///root/simplestreams/images/streams/v1/index2.json
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:473 streams/v1/index2.json not accessed, actual error: [{/build/snapcraft-juju-25888574271dd1b08771e6ebeeab8ad6/parts/juju/src/environs/simplestreams/datasource.go:192: "file:///root/simplestreams/images/streams/v1/index2.json" not found}]
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:474 streams/v1/index2.json not accessed, trying legacy index path: streams/v1/index.json
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:493 read metadata index at "file:///root/simplestreams/images/streams/v1/index.json"
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:497 skipping index "file:///root/simplestreams/images/streams/v1/index.json" because of missing information: index file has no data for cloud {microstack https://10.255.52.101:5000/v3} not found
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:967 ignoring image metadata in bootstrap metadata: index file has no data for cloud {microstack https://10.255.52.101:5000/v3} not found
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:423 searching for signed metadata in datasource "default ubuntu cloud images"
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:458 looking for data index using path streams/v1/index2.sjson
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:470 looking for data index using URL http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/streams/v1/index2.sjson
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:473 streams/v1/index2.sjson not accessed, actual error: [{/build/snapcraft-juju-25888574271dd1b08771e6ebeeab8ad6/parts/juju/src/environs/simplestreams/datasource.go:192: "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/streams/v1/index2.sjson" not found}]
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:474 streams/v1/index2.sjson not accessed, trying legacy index path: streams/v1/index.sjson
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:493 read metadata index at "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/streams/v1/index.sjson"
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:497 skipping index "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/streams/v1/index.sjson" because of missing information: index file has no data for cloud {microstack https://10.255.52.101:5000/v3} not found
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:967 ignoring image metadata in default ubuntu cloud images: index file has no data for cloud {microstack https://10.255.52.101:5000/v3} not found
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:975 found 0 image metadata from all image data sources
20:23:24 DEBUG goose logger.go:44 TRACE: MakeServiceURL: https://10.255.52.101:8774/v2.1/flavors/detail
20:23:24 INFO  cmd bootstrap.go:470 Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.9.31 for amd64
20:23:24 INFO  juju.environs.bootstrap tools.go:82 looking for bootstrap agent binaries: version=2.9.31
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.tools tools.go:87 finding agent binaries in stream: "released"
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.tools tools.go:89 reading agent binaries with major.minor version 2.9
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.tools tools.go:98 filtering agent binaries by version: 2.9.31
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.tools tools.go:101 filtering agent binaries by os type: ubuntu
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.tools tools.go:104 filtering agent binaries by architecture: amd64
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.tools urls.go:133 trying datasource "keystone catalog"
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:423 searching for signed metadata in datasource "default simplestreams"
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:458 looking for data index using path streams/v1/index2.sjson
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:754 using default candidate for content id "com.ubuntu.juju:released:agents" are {20210329 mirrors:1.0 content-download streams/v1/cpc-mirrors-agents.sjson []}
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:470 looking for data index using URL https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/streams/v1/index2.sjson
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:493 read metadata index at "https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/streams/v1/index2.sjson"
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:1025 finding products at path "streams/v1/com.ubuntu.juju-released-agents.sjson"
20:23:24 INFO  juju.environs.bootstrap tools.go:84 found 1 packaged agent binaries
20:23:24 INFO  cmd bootstrap.go:483 Located Juju agent version 2.9.31-ubuntu-amd64 at https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/agent/2.9.31/juju-2.9.31-linux-amd64.tgz
20:23:24 WARN  juju.provider.openstack config.go:181 Config attribute "use-floating-ip" is deprecated.
You can instead use the constraint "allocate-public-ip".
20:23:24 INFO  cmd bootstrap.go:578 Starting new instance for initial controller
20:23:24 INFO  cmd bootstrap.go:167 Launching controller instance(s) on microstack/microstack...
20:23:24 DEBUG goose logger.go:44 TRACE: MakeServiceURL: https://10.255.52.101:8774/v2.1/os-availability-zone
20:23:24 DEBUG goose logger.go:44 TRACE: MakeServiceURL: https://10.255.52.101:8774/v2.1/os-availability-zone
20:23:24 DEBUG goose logger.go:44 TRACE: MakeServiceURL: https://10.255.52.101:8774/v2.1/flavors/detail
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.environs.instances image.go:66 instance constraints {region: microstack, series: bionic, arch: amd64, constraints: mem=3584M, storage: []}
20:23:24 ERROR juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:884 failed to bootstrap model: cannot start bootstrap instance: no metadata for "bionic" images in microstack with arch amd64
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:885 (error details: [{/build/snapcraft-juju-25888574271dd1b08771e6ebeeab8ad6/parts/juju/src/cmd/juju/commands/bootstrap.go:984: failed to bootstrap model} {/build/snapcraft-juju-25888574271dd1b08771e6ebeeab8ad6/parts/juju/src/environs/bootstrap/bootstrap.go:706: } {/build/snapcraft-juju-25888574271dd1b08771e6ebeeab8ad6/parts/juju/src/environs/bootstrap/bootstrap.go:582: } {/build/snapcraft-juju-25888574271dd1b08771e6ebeeab8ad6/parts/juju/src/provider/common/bootstrap.go:60: } {/build/snapcraft-juju-25888574271dd1b08771e6ebeeab8ad6/parts/juju/src/provider/common/bootstrap.go:277: cannot start bootstrap instance} {/build/snapcraft-juju-25888574271dd1b08771e6ebeeab8ad6/parts/juju/src/provider/openstack/provider.go:1078: } {/build/snapcraft-juju-25888574271dd1b08771e6ebeeab8ad6/parts/juju/src/provider/openstack/provider.go:1099: } {/build/snapcraft-juju-25888574271dd1b08771e6ebeeab8ad6/parts/juju/src/provider/openstack/image.go:87: } {/build/snapcraft-juju-25888574271dd1b08771e6ebeeab8ad6/parts/juju/src/environs/instances/image.go:68: no metadata for "bionic" images in microstack with arch amd64}])
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:1641 cleaning up after failed bootstrap
20:23:24 INFO  juju.provider.common destroy.go:21 destroying model "controller"
20:23:24 INFO  juju.provider.common destroy.go:32 destroying instances
20:23:24 DEBUG goose logger.go:44 TRACE: MakeServiceURL: https://10.255.52.101:8774/v2.1/servers/detail
20:23:24 DEBUG goose logger.go:44 TRACE: MakeServiceURL: https://10.255.52.101:8774/v2.1/servers/detail
20:23:24 DEBUG juju.provider.openstack provider.go:1691 terminating instances []
20:23:25 DEBUG goose logger.go:44 DEBUG: auth details: &{Token:gAAAAABis3o9I_BvbB1iv2OXxsPzXJnBHDxVCHI3KDQl2W0e4ROMa4-544z7MBbEHTd5Sp-NZPt57ur11VfMO5YziG-duxRDS9vQXVyYsnVpgRmgZCYh8idZjhJH9rCCZnDyc9KOJ3v3BXCEEksZs21T5wZKUbozLUdWwtr0z2TWhoB7A3rLwxg TenantId:75a496aa41f944a4bd867557bcc7489d TenantName:admin UserId:47980441e7bb47a69473b734091e19d5 Domain: RegionServiceURLs:map[microstack:map[compute:https://10.255.52.101:8774/v2.1 identity:https://10.255.52.101:5000/v3/ image:https://10.255.52.101:9292 network:https://10.255.52.101:9696 placement:https://10.255.52.101:8778 volumev2:https://10.255.52.101:8776/v2/75a496aa41f944a4bd867557bcc7489d volumev3:https://10.255.52.101:8776/v3/75a496aa41f944a4bd867557bcc7489d]]}
20:23:25 DEBUG goose logger.go:44 TRACE: api version will be inserted between "https://10.255.52.101:9696/" and "/"
20:23:25 DEBUG goose logger.go:44 DEBUG: discovered API versions: [{Version:{Major:2 Minor:0} Links:[{Href:http://127.0.0.1:9686/v2.0/ Rel:self}] Status:CURRENT}]
20:23:25 DEBUG goose logger.go:44 TRACE: MakeServiceURL: https://10.255.52.101:9696/v2.0/security-groups
20:23:25 INFO  juju.provider.common destroy.go:56 destroying storage
20:23:25 DEBUG juju.provider.openstack cinder.go:119 volume URL: https://10.255.52.101:8776/v3/75a496aa41f944a4bd867557bcc7489d
20:23:25 DEBUG goose logger.go:44 TRACE: MakeServiceURL: https://10.255.52.101:9696/v2.0/security-groups
20:23:25 DEBUG goose logger.go:44 TRACE: MakeServiceURL: https://10.255.52.101:8774/v2.1/servers/detail
20:23:25 DEBUG goose logger.go:44 TRACE: MakeServiceURL: https://10.255.52.101:8774/v2.1/servers/detail
20:23:26 DEBUG goose logger.go:44 TRACE: MakeServiceURL: https://10.255.52.101:9696/v2.0/security-groups
20:23:26 INFO  cmd supercommand.go:544 command finished
```

my yaml file. I had to change `endpoint` to public address and add `ca-certificates` due to bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/microstack/+bug/1955133

```
# cat microstack.yaml 
clouds:
    microstack:
      type: openstack
      auth-types: [access-key,userpass]
      regions:
        microstack:
           endpoint: https://10.255.52.101:5000/v3
      ca-certificates:
      - |
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
        MIIC3zCCAcegAwIBAgIUWXI8I2kpUvUTQabdoZdiSqEhMg4wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
        BQAwEjEQMA4GA1UEAwwHc3RhdGxlcjAeFw0yMjA2MjEyMTUzMzNaFw0zMjA2MjEy
        MTUzMzNaMBIxEDAOBgNVBAMMB3N0YXRsZXIwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IB
        DwAwggEKAoIBAQDagPjjLmG+MmOK1mppRzEobPMQALgU1u1yF0lhwbJ7us+13PDp
        dob9VjMxJdjh088ViOXl+g/4gpRD+qumzpCT+LRYvQjlZ8EPUW/eg/tOhTm2uVR7
        N8opF24VEed6YcfA1+Zp8vocqZ7ULWlF3FEjInPAgPmM4rWtihq4FsXQA5KdZF9v
        0oktdFL4CIaWTElxNMbBSxm5tCePLbFjhRE4hRRnLlgPCE7/XsO5IzR6B8MqgcGX
        RoBE5IBaHTfXBXDnJCrQQkHyXK2a2eRYR+5YGf9odOKUqVQ6+evy6JXr1aBGnVkX
        rpw32zNW7p8XFgk+oYfveJK3Cl11v6LoVFOFAgMBAAGjLTArMA8GA1UdEwQIMAYB
        Af8CAQAwGAYDVR0RBBEwD4IHc3RhdGxlcocECv80ZTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOC
        AQEAVC9Q+MsLdMtTe/5zTfwzzml22qYELdUDgEIOg+d2kugA1UR/q9y+ub7XkFok
        9jVPO9sDq06PmYHsQZo50Rn6qbqN4z4bBIFy653ONoLf0hQkCGEnBoh1T1lqboEC
        7hpc4ZIg6qs4XlN4RtytTJev0h2vl8AvIqw/wesrbIB6PCe/ADlgDVBEcjiK11K0
        sBnZmfF+uH3asCDUfWcR1v1ubkaLQlVYPjcoqVCzjLAEjwAgu7187MWPyOl4KcHH
        1FwqRyCQx8/pkc0tZWd3j/Z3tD5Gd4GLFDMoNl36SnSUGNq37h/URkI1kQ5e6J+g
        q58wfsWLoHVaI9sLKFLl3IO+WA==
        -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```